# typeorm migrations error - "Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1"

Tags: typescript, express, typeorm

my project structure

```
src
  ...
  app.ts
ormconfig.ts
tsconfig.ts
```

**ormconfig.ts** file consists

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm'
import Company from './src/entities/Company'
require('dotenv').config()

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    // entities: ['.entities/*.ts'],
    entities: [Company],
    migrations: ['.migrations/*.ts'],
})
```

in **package.json** file code is

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npx tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/app.js\"",
    "migration:generate": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -d .ormconfig.ts",
    "migration:create": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n initial -d .ormconfig.ts",
    "migration:down": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:revert -d .ormconfig.ts"
  },
```

how do I run migration to create table to the database? when I write `npm run migration:generate` there occurs title's error.

Comment: Did you have a look here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/8810

Comment: Yes @Roar, perhaps I should not use typeorm rather prisma or sequelizer. dissapointed cz it just wasted my whole 2 days. thanks to you that you mentioned the issue.